# Maven fails with "Missing artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jdk-tools

I'm facing a Maven Dependency problem

> Missing artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6

I only have java 1.8.0_211 on my computer and all the settings in Eclipse are good (installedJREs, Build path, etc...).

Can someone explain to me why Maven keeps searching for a `jdk-tools-1.6`?